# unable to compile a lambda expression because the type isn't delegate

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to use lambda expression in C#:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
   public struct Point {
      public int x;
      public int y;

      public Point( int x, int y ) {
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
      }
   }

   public interface Mobile {
      Point getPosition();
   }

   public class Program {
      public void mth( Mobile mobile ) {
         Point p = mobile.getPosition();
         Console.WriteLine( "{ " + p.x + ", " + p.y + " }" );
      }

      static void Main( string[] args ) {
         new Program().mth( () => { return new Point( 4, 5 ); } ); <<<<<<<< ERROR
      }
   }
}
```

Compiler error (in French):

> Impossible de convertir expression lambda en type
>   'ConsoleApplication1.Mobile', car il ne s'agit pas d'un type délégué

International English Translation:

> Unable to convert lambda expression to type
>   'ConsoleApplication1.Mobile', because isn't a delegate type

**What's the right syntax?**

Comment: Are you trying to implement that interface method using a lambda?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here - it looks like you want to `getPosition()` from `Mobile` but you are trying to create one using an anonymous function that returns a `Point`... can you explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be confusing an *interface* and a *delegate*.

An *interface* is, roughly speaking, a collection of one or more methods. It *has* to be implemented by a class that provides implementations for each method; you can't build an implementation up from lambda methods.

A *delegate* is basically a named method signature. You can convert a lambda method to a delegate as long as the signature is correct, or you can create a delegate pointing at a method on a class, say.

I *think* what you're after to make your code work is to turn your `Mobile` into a delegate:

```
// This can represent any function that takes nothing and returns a point.
public delegate Point Mobile();

public class Program {

    // This takes any "Mobile" function, calls it and displays the result.      
    public void mth(Mobile getPosition) {
        Point p = getPosition();
        Console.WriteLine("{ " + p.x + ", " + p.y + " }");
    }

    // This calls mth with a lambda that matches the "Mobile" definition.
    static void Main( string[] args ) {
        new Program().mth(() => { return new Point( 4, 5 ); }); 
    }

    // You could also explicitly create a "Mobile".
    static void Main2( string[] args ) {
        Mobile myMobile = new Mobile(() => { return new Point( 4, 5 ); });
        new Program().mth(myMobile); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is it.

Comment: Yes! That's THE answer! The concept of delegate is newer for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
   public class Mobile {
      public Func<Point> GetPosition { get; set; }
   }

   public class Program {
      public void mth( Mobile mobile ) {
         Point p = mobile.GetPosition();
         Console.WriteLine( "{ " + p.x + ", " + p.y + " }" );
      }

      static void Main( string[] args ) {
         new Program().mth( new Mobile { GetPosition = () => { return new Point( 4, 5 ); } } ); 
      }
   }
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot adding getter-setter for GetPosition property